# Issue with AVL tree rotations

Tags: c++, rotation, avl-tree

I have been working on an AVL tree for insertions.  I have the inserts working properly but every implementation of my rotations I have tried will not work.  I have been trying different locations for my balancing and also just attempting to rotate after each insertion just to check if it would work but I am not getting a rotation to fire at all.  Any help with why my rotations are not working would be greatly appreciated.

header:

```
#ifndef LINKEDBINARYTREE_H
#define LINKEDBINARYTREE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class LinkedBinaryTree {
private:
    struct Node {
        string word;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        Node* parent;
        int wordCount;
        int height;
        Node() : word(), left(NULL), right(NULL), parent(NULL), wordCount(1), height(1) {}
        Node(string s, Node* l, Node* r, Node* p) {
            word = s;
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
            parent = p;
            wordCount = 1;
            height = 1;
        }
    };
    Node* _root;

public:
    LinkedBinaryTree();
    ~LinkedBinaryTree();
    void insertNode(Node* node, string word);
    void insert(string word);
    void display(Node* ptr, int level);
    Node* root();
    void inOrder(Node* node);
    void rightRotate(Node* node);
    void leftRotate(Node* node);
    void rightLeftRotate(Node* node);
    void leftRightRotate(Node* node);
    int avlNum(Node* node);
    int height(Node* node);
    int bfactor(Node* node);
    void fixHeight(Node* node);
    void balance(Node* node);

    int n;
};
#endif
```

.cpp:

```
#include "LinkedBinaryTree.h"
#include <algorithm>

void LinkedBinaryTree::inOrder(Node * node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    inOrder(node->left);
    cout << node->word << " " << avlNum(node) << " : " ;
    inOrder(node->right);
}

void LinkedBinaryTree::rightRotate(Node* node)
{
    Node* temp;
    temp = node->left;
    node->left = temp->right;
    temp->right = node;
    temp->parent = node->parent;
    node = temp;
    if (temp->parent = NULL) {
        _root = temp;
    }
    fixHeight(node);
    fixHeight(node->right);
    fixHeight(node->left);
}

void LinkedBinaryTree::leftRotate(Node * node)
{
    Node* temp;
    temp = node->right;
    node->right = temp->left;
    temp->left = node;
    temp->parent = node->parent;
    node = temp;
    if (temp->parent = NULL) {
        _root = temp;
    }
    fixHeight(node);
    fixHeight(node->right);
    fixHeight(node->left);
}

void LinkedBinaryTree::rightLeftRotate(Node * node)
{
    rightRotate(node->left);
    leftRotate(node);
}

void LinkedBinaryTree::leftRightRotate(Node * node)
{
    leftRotate(node->right);
    rightRotate(node);
}

int LinkedBinaryTree::height(Node * node)
{
    int h = 0;

    if (node != NULL) {
        h = node->height;
    }
    return h;
}

int LinkedBinaryTree::bfactor(Node * node)
{
    return height(node->right) - height(node->left);
}

void LinkedBinaryTree::fixHeight(Node * node)
{
    int hl = height(node->left);
    int hr = height(node->right);
    node->height = (hl > hr ? hl : hr) + 1;
}

int LinkedBinaryTree::avlNum(Node * node)
{
    int leftH = height(node->left);
    int rightH = height(node->right);
    int avlNum = rightH - leftH;
    return avlNum;
}

LinkedBinaryTree::LinkedBinaryTree()
{
    _root = NULL;
}

LinkedBinaryTree::~LinkedBinaryTree()
{
}

void LinkedBinaryTree::insertNode(Node* node, string word)
{
    if (word < node->word) {
        if (node->left != NULL)
            insertNode(node->left, word);
        else {
            node->left = new Node(word, NULL, NULL, node);
        }   
    }
    else if (word > node->word)
    {
        if (node->right != NULL)
            insertNode(node->right, word);
        else {
            node->right = new Node(word, NULL, NULL, node);
        }
    }
    else if (word == node->word) {
        node->wordCount++;
    }
    balance(node);
}

void LinkedBinaryTree::insert(string word) {

    if (_root == NULL) {
        _root = new Node(word, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        n++;
    }
    else {
        insertNode(_root, word);
        n++;
    }
}
void LinkedBinaryTree::display(Node* ptr, int level)
{
    int i;
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        display(ptr->right, level + 1);
        printf("\n");
        if (ptr == _root)
            cout << "Root -> ";
        for (i = 0; i < level && ptr != _root; i++)
            cout << "        ";
        cout << ptr->word;
        display(ptr->left, level + 1);
    }
}

LinkedBinaryTree::Node * LinkedBinaryTree::root()
{
    return _root;
}

void LinkedBinaryTree::balance(Node* node) 
{
    fixHeight(node);
    if (bfactor(node) == 2) {
        if (bfactor(node->right) < 0)
            rightRotate(node->right);
        else
            leftRotate(node);
    }
    if (bfactor(node) == 2) {
        if (bfactor(node->left) > 0)
            leftRotate(node->left);
        else
            rightRotate(node);
    }
}
```

main:

```
#include "LinkedBinaryTree.h"
#include <string>

int main() {

    LinkedBinaryTree t;

    t.insert("Yes");
    t.insert("No");
    t.insert("Maybe");
    t.insert("Hopefully");
    t.insert("Absolutely");

    t.display(t.root(), 1);

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    t.inOrder(t.root());

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous errors in your code, but the one that is preventing the rotations is the second `bfactor` check in `balance` is incorrect.  It should compare with `-2`.

```
if (bfactor(node) == -2)
```

One other issue you have is assignments in the conditions of `if` statements in your `Rotate` functions (increasing your compiler warning level would inform you of these).

Comment: ah thank you, ya i missed the -2.  I have made those changes in my code but it is still not fixing the issue.  "Yes" is always the root not matter what happens which I dont understand because even if nothing else is rotating once a rotation is fired it should change the root of the tree.

Comment: @NeerP84 Did you fix the `if (temp->parent = NULL)` to be `if (temp->parent == NULL)`?

Comment: that fixed it, thank you.  I am still losing nodes after the 4th insertion tho